# Discord JS npm install discord.js Problem

Tags: windows, npm, discord.js

```
C:\Users\PC\Documents\bot> npm install discord.js
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\PC\Documents\bot\node_modules\.staging\setimmediate-ba27c7e7\LICENSE.txt'
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\PC\Documents\bot\node_modules\.staging\discord.js-4ced0e0d\webpack\discord.js.LICENSE.txt'
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-13T21_02_55_389Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Looks like you need permission to install npm... On unix systems this would require a `sudo` in-front of your `npm install`... Not sure about Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you have npm version 5 or above, try this first:

```
$ npm cache verify
```

Otherwise:

```
$ npm cache clean
```

This error should be related to your cache, if not then try reinstalling npm and node.